# Compiler error, mocking C++ unit test with static polymorpism

Tags: c++

I'm trying to apply static polymorphism for unit testing

```
template<typename T, typename Output> class HistogramWriter
{
public:
    static void write(const RGBHistogram<T> &hist, Output &output)
    {
       output << "ABCD" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Now I'm trying to make Output to a mocking class for unit testing

```
struct TestMock
{
    std::string data;
};

istream& operator>>(istream &stream, TestMock &mock)
{
    stream >> mock.data;
}
```

If I set T to int and Output to TestMock, it doesn't work. Of course if I set Output to std::cout, it would work.

I'm trying to copy the string to TestMock's data. But I just don't know how to do it, the compiler is complaining binary '<<' no operator found

Comment: Really? I'm very confused. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Can you provide a complete testcase that we can try compiling and see for ourselves what you mean? I am confused at how your both code snippets should work together and how op<< comes into that game.

Comment: A bit difficult to pull it out... The code is a simple pushing strings to a std::cout. I just mocked std::cout to Output and want to replace it with my custom class that I can use for unit test mocking.

Answer (score 2):

The `HistogramWriter::write` uses the output operator to write to `output`. However, you 
do not provide any output operator for your `TestMock` class, only an input operator.

Also, the `output` parameter is expected to be a *stream* that you can output *to*, by defining an `operator<<` for your `TestMock` class, you only tell the compiler how to output an *instance of `TestMock`* to a stream, you do not define the stream itself.

To solve this you have to declare the output operator *inside* the class, using templates. Something like this:

```
struct TestMock
{
    std::string data;

    template<class T>
    TestMock& operator<<(const T& value)
    {
        std::ostringstream os;
        os << value;
        data += os.str();
        return *this;
    }
};
```

The above code will make an instance of `TestMock` to behave like a stream, and all output sent to it will be appended to the `data` member variable.

I suggest you read up more on input and output operators, and how to overload/override them.

Comment: I guess I'm confused whether I should operator>> or operator<< for my purpose.

Comment: @Kinderchocolate Please see my updated answer for a solution on how you can do.

Comment: There I was going about doing a friend std::ostream& operator<< solution, and it was getting stupidly complex, and you come along with this. :-D